# My header not showing up

Tags: headers

I'm starting a brand new theme and my `header.php`'s content is not being output to the browser, the browser is just plainly ignoring it.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I just wasn't calling it by get_header(), sorry!

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by _Not working_? Put a simple _Hello_ in it and see if it appears in the console.

Comment: nop, that is what is not working :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply having a `header.php` in your theme's folder will not output your header to the browser. You have to call the header too.

To call the `header.php` file, you should use `get_header();` at the top of almost every template (Almost!) such as `page.php`, `single.php`, `archive.php` and so on.

Do the same for `footer.php` to get the footer.

I can't quite recall the full list, but these are the main files:

```
archive.php
author.php
category.php
date.php
front-page.php
home.php
index.php
page.php
single.php
singular.php
search.php
tag.php
taxonomy.php
```

This also applies to child pages, and child theme's pages, such as `page-abc.php`.

Also, take a look at the [WP Hierarchy](http://wphierarchy.com/) schematic. This is greatly useful for those who want to start developing themes.

Comment: you got it man, i actually knew that but apparently i deleted it accidentally.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You are most welcome. I've added a link too, you mind find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for the template hierarchy!!, so helpful!!, exactly what i needed!!